# What should I do to fix SonarLint warning "remove usage of generic wildcard type"

Tags: java, sonarqube

When I use SonarLint plugin to scan the Java code in IntelliJ IDEA, it shows warning like this:

> remove usage of generic wildcard type.

This is the Java code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public interface IAsyncTestService
{

    Future<?> submit(Runnable task);

}
```

What should I do to avoid this warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use generic type or actual type for return type of method declaration

```
public interface IAsyncTestService<T>
{
    Future<T> submit(Runnable task);
}
```

Or

```
public interface IAsyncTestService
{
    <T> Future<T> submit(Runnable task);
}
```

Or specific type:

```
public interface IAsyncTestService
{
    Future<String> submit(Runnable task);
}
```

Comment: The `interface` doesn't say anything about `Future<T>` ...

Answer (score 2):

Replace wildcard type `<?>` with an actual type parameter; eg. `<T>`.
Which one it is obviously depends on what the `Future` might return.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

The expected signature should be `Future<V>` - or a specific type.